# how to use min-height, aspect-ratio, ... with container queries?

Tags: html, css, container-queries

I am currently struggling with container queries. As long as I just use min-width and max-width everything is fine and works well. As soon as I try to use logic operators like and/or it doesn´t work anymore.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  container-name: wrapper;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.box {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@container wrapper (min-width: 300px) {
  .box {
    background-color: #00ff00;
  }
}

@container wrapper (min-width: 300px) and (min-height: 0px) {
  .box {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the codepen here: https://codepen.io/Resolver1412/pen/dygxWKY

I would expect that the box would become red instead of green. Since the last container query would overwrite the previous one.

Anyone knows whats wrong or what might have happened? I currently use this chrome version: Version 112.0.5615.121

Comment: To garner more feedback, you might try to rephrase your title as a question.
Reference the stackoverflow how-to for more guidance:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs:

> The `inline-size` CSS property defines the horizontal or vertical size
> of an element's block, depending on its writing mode. It corresponds
> to either the width or the height property, depending on the value of
> `writing-mode`.
>
> – [inline-size | MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size)

In your example, since [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) has the default value of `horizontal-tb`, only `width` is usable in `@container` queries.

You can switch to `container-type: size` to use both inline and block size in queries:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  container-name: wrapper;
  container-type: size;
}

@container wrapper (width >= 300px) and (height >= 0px) {
  .box {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

Try it:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  container-name: wrapper;
  container-type: size;
}

.box {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@container wrapper (width >= 300px) {
  .box {
    background-color: #00ff00;
  }
}

@container wrapper (width >= 300px) and (height >= 0px) {
  .box {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, you can use `aspect-ratio` instead of `width` and `height`:

```css
@container wrapper (aspect-ratio > 1 / 2) {
  .box {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

Try it:

```css
.wrapper {
  container-name: wrapper;
  container-type: size;
}

.box {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@container wrapper (width >= 300px) {
  .box {
    background-color: #00ff00;
  }
}

@container wrapper (aspect-ratio > 1 / 2) {
  .box {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so in which cases is aspect-ratio available for example? Looks like I have to decide which orientation I want to use?

Comment: @Max You can use `size` for that. See updated answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the in depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `container-type` to `size`.

This causes the horizontal and vertical axis to be taken into account.

[CSS_container_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries)

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 300px;
  container-name: wrapper;
  container-type: size;
}

.box{
  background-color: #0000ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@container wrapper (min-width: 300px) {
  .box {
    background-color: #00ff00;
  }
}

@container wrapper (min-width: 300px) and (min-height: 0px) {
  .box {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box">
     <span>test</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not have any effect for me.

Comment: Ah. OK. its working in firefox, but not in chrome.