# CSS Container query (aspect-ratio) not working

Tags: container-queries

I'm trying to apply some styles based on the aspect-ratio of the container `<div>` element, but I haven't managed to write the correct [Container query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries) code.

If I take [the Mozilla docs word on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container#descriptors) (assuming I understand it correctly) it should be something possible to achieve, but that page lacks an example of this particular combination (e.g. an example of `@container` with `aspect-ratio` descriptor).

I'm using the most recent version of Google Chrome browser, so I assume Container queries are [supported out of the box](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40container).

I'm trying to make the `flex-direction` attribute value change based on the container aspect ratio.

Here is the relevant part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="a">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

and the accompanying CSS code:

```
.cont {
  container-type: size;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.a,.b {
  max-width: 1rem;
}


@container (aspect-ratio > 1 / 1) {
  .cont {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

Those snippets come from [this `Codepen`](https://codepen.io/lucrus/pen/yLZpwwZ) of mine. As you can see, the container queries just seem to be ignored by the browser.

I also tried `container-type: inline-size;`, but that made no difference (not that I expected it to make any, but I tried just in case).

Suspecting problems about `display: flex;` on the container I tried `display: block;` instead and used `background-color` instead of `flex-direction`, but even that did not work.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76390266/1483447) to a similar question seems to suggest my code, in the query descriptor part, is correct, or at least I can't spot what mistake I'm doing when comparing my code with that answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container query styling doesn't affect the container specifying the container context itself. They do work on elements within the container context, i.e. on elements with an ancestor specifying a container context.

I was able to get your solution working with a small modification by using an inner element as the flexbox. To see it in action, change the container's width of `10rem` to `1rem` and watch the flex direction change from column to row.

HTML:

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="flexer">
    <div class="a">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.cont {
  container-type: size;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

.flexer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.a,.b {
  max-width: 1rem;
}

@container (aspect-ratio > 1 / 1) {
  .flexer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

`container-type` property isn't part of the CSS specification, so using it won't have any effect. Instead, you should use @container queries directly.

CSS:

```
.cont {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.a, .b {
  max-width: 1rem;
}
```

JS:

```
function updateFlexDirection() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.cont');
  const aspectRatio = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
  
  if (aspectRatio > 1) {
    container.style.flexDirection = 'row';
  } else {
    container.style.flexDirection = 'column';
  }
}

// Initial call to set the flex-direction based on initial aspect ratio
updateFlexDirection();

// Listen for window resize events to update flex-direction
window.addEventListener('resize', updateFlexDirection);
```

Comment: `container-type` is part of the [CSS3 spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain-3/#container-type) and [can be used](https://caniuse.com/?search=container%20query) by modern browsers

Comment: sure, if I could use JS... (aside the fact CSS3 does include @container queries)